# Which aggregate function to use in the following pivot clause?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table `Players` which has two columns : `Name` and `Sport_Played`. 
Sample data would be like:

```
Name.       Sport _played
Ravi            Cricket
Raju            Cricket 
Ronaldo     Football
Messi         Football
Anand        Chess
```

I want to pivot the table having columns as sport played and the columns should contain the names of players sorted ascendingly.

```
Cricket         Football         Chess
Raju              Messi            Anand
Ravi              Ronaldo        Null
```

The problem is that pivot requires an aggregate function. What aggregate function to use to display the names of players as part of column of sport played. Thanks.

Comment: "having columns as sport played and the columns should contain the names of players" you have these two columns already; why do you need a pivot and not just to sort the result set?

Comment: I was learning pivot. Just want to implement it

Comment: Please update your question with a [MCVE] including an example of your expected output for your sample data.

Comment: Sure done the editing @MT0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an example of how you want your output it is difficult to know what you are intending but:

> having columns as sport played and the columns should contain the names of players sorted ascendingly

You do not need to use `PIVOT`, you can use `LISTAGG`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50382/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE players ( Name, Sport_played ) AS
SELECT 'Ravi',    'Cricket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Raju',    'Cricket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ronaldo', 'Football' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Messi',   'Football' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Anand',   'Chess' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT sport_played,
       LISTAGG( name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY name ) As names
FROM   players
GROUP BY sport_played
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50382/1/0)**:

```
| SPORT_PLAYED |         NAMES |
|--------------|---------------|
|        Chess |         Anand |
|      Cricket |     Raju,Ravi |
|     Football | Messi,Ronaldo |
```

**Update**:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50382/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE players ( Name, Sport_played ) AS
SELECT 'Ravi',    'Cricket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Raju',    'Cricket' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ronaldo', 'Football' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Messi',   'Football' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Anand',   'Chess' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   ( SELECT p.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Sport_played
                                    ORDER BY name ) AS rn
          FROM players p )
PIVOT (
  MAX( Name )
  FOR Sport_Played IN (
    'Cricket' As Cricket,
    'Football' As Football,
    'Chess' AS Chess
  )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50382/2/0)**:

```
| RN | CRICKET | FOOTBALL |  CHESS |
|----|---------|----------|--------|
|  1 |    Raju |    Messi |  Anand |
|  2 |    Ravi |  Ronaldo | (null) |
```

You can use any (string) aggregation function in the `PIVOT` including `MAX(name)`, `MIN(name)` or even [`LISTAGG( name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Name )`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50382/5). The `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function will generate a unique number-per-sport so the aggregation function will only ever work on a single value so it does not matter what aggregation function is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MT0. I agree its my bad but now i have edited the question. Can you help me now.

Comment: @JotWaraich Updated

Comment: You can use `MAX(name)`, `MIN(name)` or even `LISTAGG( name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY Name )` as the aggregation function.